# Wkhtmltopdf on Alpine linux, segmentation fault (core dumped) error when converting html to pdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux

I'm using Alpine linux version 3.14 and installed the package for wkhtmltopdf here:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/wkhtmltopdf

Package installs correctly and wkhtmltopdf --version responds me correctly.

The problem is that when trying to launch the command to convert any simple html file I get the error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

This happen with any html, also the simplest without fonts or other complex stuff.

Could anyone explain me istructions to compile correctly wkhtmltopdf from source on Alpine 3.14?

Comment: This sounds like something that the wkhtmltopdf github issues might help with

Comment: I am having the same problem and as well with archlinux in aarch64 architecture. I found https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/issues/30 and it seems the issue was solved. My version is 0.12.6. Did you find a solution?